# Can't run background thread locally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I working on a task from my textbook and it suggests to make two thread main and background one. But browsers cannot load data from local device for background thread, can they? What do I do in this scenario?

I tried using Google Chrome, IE, FireFox, it is still the same result, but in FireFox it says:

```
Security Error: Content at file:///C:/Users/Professional/Downloads/FTP/12/ex12.3/12.3.html may not load data from file:///C:/Users/Professional/Downloads/FTP/12/ex12.3/12.3.js.
```

Comment: You need to run a local webserver

Comment: Thanks man, I thought about it, but did not know it was necessary, I'll try it

Comment: But I thought maybe there is some different solution, I am completely novice to web-developing and programming overall

Comment: No there is no other way then using a webserver. You might use an existing webserver service, where you can upload your code. Depending on the structure of your code you might be able to test on services like codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: Yeah, online editor worked for me, I guess I'm learning